# Stirling's approximation from Euler-Maclaurin formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, euler-maclaurin

I try to derive Stirling's approximation from Euler-Maclaurin formula with form:
$$\sum_{x=m}^nf(x)=\int_m^n{f(x)dx}+\frac{f(n)+f(m)}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^p{\frac{(-1)^kB_k}{k!}[f^{(k-1)}(n)-f^{(k-1)}(m)]+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p!}\int_m^n{f^{(p)}(x)P_p(x)dx}}$$
$P_p(x)$ is periodic Bernoulli functions,
$B_k$ is Bernoulli number,when $f(x)=\ln(x)$ and $m=1$，get:
$$
\sum_{x=1}^n\ln(x)=\int_1^n{\ln(x)dx}+\frac{\ln(n)+\ln(1)}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^p{\frac{(-1)^kB_k}{k!}[\ln^{(k-1)}(n)-\ln^{(k-1)}(1)]+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p!}\int_1^n{f^{(p)}(x)P_p(x)dx}} 
\\
=n\ln(n)-n+1+\frac{\ln(n)}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^p{\frac{(-1)^kB_k}{k!}\ln^{(k-1)}(n)+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p!}\int_1^n{f^{(p)}(x)P_p(x)dx}}
\\
=n\ln(n)-n+1+\frac{\ln(n)}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^p{\frac{(-1)^kB_k}{k!}{\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-2)!}{n^{k-1}}}+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p!}\int_1^n{f^{(p)}(x)P_p(x)dx}}
\\
=n\ln(n)-n+1+\frac{\ln(n)}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^p{\frac{(-1)^kB_k}{k(k-1)n^{k-1}}+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p!}\int_1^n{f^{(p)}(x)P_p(x)dx}}
\\
$$
so that:
$$\ln(n!)-\frac{\ln(n)}{2}=\sum_{x=1}^n\ln(x)-\frac{\ln(n)}{2}\\=n\ln(n)-n+1+\sum_{k=2}^p{\frac{(-1)^kB_k}{k(k-1)n^{k-1}}+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{p!}\int_1^n{f^{(p)}(x)P_p(x)dx}}
$$
but on [wikipedia]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation
the form is :
$$\ln(n!)-\frac{\ln(n)}{2}=n\ln(n)-n+1+\sum_{k=2}^p{\frac{(-1)^kB_k}{k(k-1)}\left(\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}-1\right)+R_{m,n}}
$$
Where am I wrong?And what is the actual formula of $R_{m,n}$

Comment: Why do you think you're wrong?  Also, the link you give references the Euler-Maclaurin formula article which discusses the [error term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_remainder_term), $R_{m,n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are the bounds of the integral.

Comment: @EricTowers I had read the link,but I am not sure whether the form $\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}$ became $\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}-1$ is relating with the error term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just sort of dropped that $\ln^{(k-1)}(1)$ term up there, and although $\ln(1)=0$, its derivatives aren't, and that's where wikipedia got $\left(\frac1{n^{k-1}}-1\right)$ vs. your $\frac1{n^{k-1}}$. It doesn't really matter though, because that term could have been $42$ for all that wikipedia did with it in the next line or so when they used the Wallis product to estimate that all the constant stuff amounted to $\frac12\ln(2\pi)$.

Comment: Why $ln^{(k-1)}(1)=0$ is not correct?

Comment: Because $\ln^{(0)}(1)=\ln(1)=0$, $\ln^{(1)}(1)=\frac11=1$, $\ln^{(2)}(1)=-\frac1{1^2}=-1$, $\ln^{(3)}(1)=\frac2{1^3}\cdots$